# The boundary of an open half-ball is contained in a union of two spheres ? (Lee's smooth manifold))

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I found some argument in the proof of the following lemma in Lee's smooth manifold 2ed is confusing.

> $\textbf{Lemma 16.2}$ Suppose $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$, and $K$ is a compact subset of $U$. Then there is an open $\textit{domain of integration}$ (defined as bounded subset where its boundary has measure zero) $D$ such that $K \subseteq D \subseteq \bar{D} \subseteq U$.
>
> $\textbf{Proof.}$ For each $p \in K$, there is an open ball or half-ball containing $p$ whose closure  is contained in $U$. By compactness, finitely many such sets $B_1,\dots, B_m$ cover
> $K$. Since the boundary of an open ball is a codimension-1 submanifold, and $\color{red}{\text{the boundary of an open half-ball is contained in a union of two such submanifolds}}$, the boundary of each has measure zero by Corollary 6.12. The set $D= B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_m$ is the required domain of integration.

I find it difficult to follow the red color part in the proof above. How can the boundary of open half-ball can be covered by union of two submanifolds. I know that the submanifolds referred above are the boundary of open ball, which is a sphere. Can anyone explain this to me ? Thank you.

Comment: The boundary of an open half ball, is the union of a hemisphere of the same radius, and a closed ball of one smaller dimension, which is like the cross section of the sphere across the great circle created by the edge of the hemisphere. Look at it in three dimensions for a clearer picture.

Comment: Thank you @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг. But i'm aware of that too. Is it possible that what Lee's means is the explanation that you just described ? Based on the text i thought what the author mean is that the boundary of an open half ball is contained in a union of two spheres of same codimension.

Comment: @Sau I can see your confusion coming from "two *such* submanifolds",  but I am still inclined to think that what we are both aware of , *is* the case. In particular, the argument still applies, since both are submanifolds of codimension greater than or equal to one. So, the proof should go through, although doubts on what was meant will linger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary of a half-ball is contained in the union of an $(n-1)$-sphere and an $(n-1)$-dimensional linear subspace, each of which is a smooth codimension-$1$ submanifold.

Comment: Thanks for clear this up Prof. Lee. This really help.